# Disabling OK button of JFace-InputDialog when input is not valid

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, swt, jface

I am trying to get a value through the Eclipse JFace input dialog using following instruction.

```
InputDialog inputDialog = new InputDialog(parentShell, dialogTitle, dialogMessage, initialValue, null);
    if (inputDialog.open() == Window.OK)
    {
        return inputDialog.getValue();
    }
```

What I want to do is to validate the input string. If the string is not valid (with some logic), Disable the OK button.

In simple words, Enable OK button when input string is valid. Can I implement that in the validator method?.

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot find class `InputDialog` in Java 8 SE. Probably you can post a [mcve] here?

Comment: Yes, you need a reference to the button though, how is it implemented?

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy Looks more like SWT :/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this with the validator. `InputDialog` will disable the OK button automatically if the `IInputValidator.isValid` method returns a non-null string. OK will be enabled again when the validator returns `null`.

Comment: Yes. I have created a IInputValidator and able to get the error message for non null return values of isValid. And Ok is disabled.

Comment: But need to add a note (message) on the same promt. Thinking how to do it. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The string returned by isValid is displayed below the input text field. If you want to do something else that is a new question.